# UIDatePicker selected date does not appear

Tags: ios, nsdate, uidatepicker

UIDatePickerView is working fine.  It shows up, I can scroll through the dates, but for some reason my selectedOB.text keeps coming up as Todays date!  No matter what date I choose, it shows as todays date!

I select this:
[image]

NSLog and the label shows up as:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)selectDOB:(id)sender 
{
    UIActionSheet *selectBirthMY = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Date of Birth" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Select", nil];
    [selectBirthMY setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
    [selectBirthMY showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
    [selectBirthMY setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 500)];
}

- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 216)];
    pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    [pickerView setMinuteInterval:15];
    //Add picker to action sheet
    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
    //Gets an array af all of the subviews of our actionSheet

    NSArray *subviews = [actionSheet subviews];
    [[subviews objectAtIndex:1] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 265, 280, 46)];
    [[subviews objectAtIndex:2] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 317, 280, 46)];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UIDatePicker *DOBPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, YYYY"];

    NSDate *pickedDOB = [DOBPicker date];
    NSString *DOB = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:pickedDOB];
    NSLog (@"This is DOB %@", DOB);
    self.selectedDOB.text=DOB;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two different instances of UIDatePicker. You need to use the same instance of datePicker to get the selected date

Make a property for datePicker

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDatePicker *pickerView;

- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    if(!self.pickerView){
        self.pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 216)];
        self.pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

        [self.pickerView setMinuteInterval:15];
        //Add picker to action sheet
        [actionSheet addSubview:self.pickerView];
    }

    //Gets an array af all of the subviews of our actionSheet

    NSArray *subviews = [actionSheet subviews];
    [[subviews objectAtIndex:1] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 265, 280, 46)];
    [[subviews objectAtIndex:2] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 317, 280, 46)];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, YYYY"];

    NSDate *pickedDOB = [self.pickerView date];
    NSString *DOB = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:pickedDOB];
    NSLog (@"This is DOB %@", DOB);
    self.selectedDOB.text=DOB;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are allocating new instance of UIDatePicker in this method

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

So don't create new instance . Use already created datepicker instance .

Hope it helps you.